# SQL to LINQ Tool

Tags: sql, linq

Is there a tool out there which can convert SQL syntax to LINQ syntax?

I just want to rewrite basic queries with join, etc., to [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). It would save me a lot of time.

Comment: There is this tool that uses AI nowadays that converts SQL into C# LINQ. It's [Linq Me Up](https://www.linqmeup.com)

Comment: I have just found that Co-Pilot can do quite a good job. With the free version the size of the prompt is limited - I had to remove columns  to just get the essential structure. It was able to handle left join / outer apply to an aggregate subquery - though it did not quite get the most elegant handling of null conversions.
This may not do what you want if your intent is to do large queries.
Chat GPT 3.5 was nearly there but its code had some errors.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Edit 7/17/2020: I cannot delete this accepted answer. It used to be good, but now it isn't. Beware really old posts, guys. I'm removing the link.

[**Linqer**] is a SQL to LINQ converter tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and convert your existing SQL statements.

Not every SQL statement can be converted to LINQ, but Linqer covers many different types of SQL expressions. Linqer supports both .NET languages - C# and Visual Basic.

Comment: Very buggy.  Installer failed for me with "invalid license" message popping up.

Comment: Same problem for me.  Release notes said they fixed the problem, but not on my network I guess.

Comment: Norton Security Flagged this as bad news!

Comment: AVG reported the 4.6 version as a Trojan!!! Atros3.AKZX. A bug in AVG?

Comment: Looks like it's had no support for 2½ years.  I could not even install Linqer correctly. Failed on me with an error: "Not suppported Entity Framework version 0", spelling mistake & all.

Comment: I had to give up on this tool.  Apparently I have to generate some kind of model (WHY? I want to convert a very simple 4 line SQL query!) and when I tried to do that it threw an exception because it couldn't find something in Program Files\Windows SDKs. what?

Comment: this is old now and I cannot delete it.

Comment: You have to start it ones with admin rights, and set the path to the SqlMetal.exe, a tool from .Net Framework. It is hard linked to the .NET 4.6 , but any other would also do.

Answer (score 36):

I know that this isn't what you asked for but [LINQPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) is a really great tool to teach yourself [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) (and it's free :o).

When time isn't critical, I have been using it for the last week or so instead or a query window in [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and my LINQ skills are getting better and better.

It's also a nice little code snippet tool. Its only downside is that the free version doesn't have [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelli-sense).

Comment: It's freemium, not free.

Answer (score 29):

[Bill Horst's - Converting SQL to LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/11/19/converting-sql-to-linq-part-1-the-basics-bill-horst.aspx) is a very good resource for this task (as well as [**LINQPad**](http://www.linqpad.net/)).

[LINQ Tools](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/LINQ-Tools.aspx) has a decent list of tools as well but I do not believe there is anything else out there that can do what Linqer did.

---

Generally speaking, LINQ is a higher-level querying language than SQL which can cause translation loss when trying to convert SQL to LINQ. For one, LINQ emits shaped results and SQL flat result sets. The issue here is that an automatic translation from SQL to LINQ will often have to perform more *transliteration* than translation - generating examples of how NOT to write LINQ queries. For this reason, there are few (if any) tools that will be able to reliably convert SQL to LINQ.  Analogous to learning C# 4 by first converting VB6 to C# 4 and then studying the resulting conversion.

Comment: the link that you provided that's existe!

Comment: Early 2020 link to the Bill Horst reference : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/converting-sql-to-linq-part-1-the-basics-bill-horst/