# Convert SQL to LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm having great trouble in converting the following SQL to LINQ to SQL, any one able to help out?

```
SELECT     dbo.ExpensesGroup.ExpenseGroupId, dbo.ExpensesGroup.Title, SUM(dbo.Expenses.Amount) AS TotalAmount, MAX(dbo.Expenses.DateLastTickled) 
                      AS LastTickledDate, MAX(dbo.ExpensesGroup.DateTime) AS Date, Username
FROM         dbo.Expenses INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ExpensesGroup ON dbo.Expenses.ExpenseId = dbo.ExpensesGroup.ExpensesId
WHERE     dbo.Expenses.Status = 'AwaitingApproval' or dbo.Expenses.Status = 'AwaitingApprovelGrouping'
GROUP BY dbo.ExpensesGroup.ExpenseGroupId, dbo.ExpensesGroup.Title, dbo.Expenses.Username
ORDER BY MAX(dbo.ExpensesGroup.DateTime) DESC, dbo.ExpensesGroup.Title
```

Or even better anyone know of an automatic SQl to LINQ converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool) existing thread.

If you decide to do it by hand, [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) should be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I tried linqpad but its not for converting SQL to linq but its actual use is to replace sql with linq to query your database

however I think linqer is the right choice if you like to convert SQL query to LINQ. 
you can download it from their official site.

http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: answer is no. i didn't tried to find too hard if you find one please leave a comment down there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

linqpad don't convert.

free converter

http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/sql-to-linq-converter

Note: Run with SQLite in Windows, not WindowsPhone necesary

Comment: the hyperlink is dead

Answer (score -2):

To go from LINQ -> SQL try this:

```
        var db = new DBModelDataContext();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        db.Log = sw; //set the writer

        var items = (from rec in db.Table1
                     select rec).ToList();

        var sql = sb.ToString(); //here is the SQL from LINQ.
```

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: opposite of question