# Lookup using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to do lookup cross 2 tables using Entity Framework unfortunately I couldn't find way but I do have sql query which does what I want

SQL Query

```
select top(1) p1.Percentage
from LookupTable p1 , [lookupTablePerUnit] p2
where p2.[LookupValue] &lt;= @Value1  and p1.ID=p2.[LookupID]
order BY pr.range DESC
```

if @Value1= 6 then The result = 52

Here is a screenshot of two tables (lookupTable && LookTablePerUnit) using this query

```
(SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[lookupTablePerUnit] p1 , [DB].[dbo].[LookupTable] p2
where p1.LookupTableID = p2.ID)
```

http://s15.postimage.org/m80zvn4mx/Captur2e.png

Comment: Similar questions have been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339732/convert-sql-to-linq-to-sql.

Comment: I couldn't find the solution through the links you provided, even I tried this tool (LINQPAD). No luck .... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A join (your query is using the implicit join syntax for SQL) would look very similar in Linq to Entities:

```
var query = from p1 in context.LookupTable 
            join p2 in context.lookupTablePerUnit on p1.ID equals p2.LookupID
            where p2.LookupValue <= Value1
            orderby p1.range descending
            select p1.Percentage;

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Had to take a guess on the `range` property you have a typo in your question so its not clear whether it can be attributed to `LookupTable` or `lookupTablePerUnit`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (hope you're using C#):

```
int value1 = 6;
int percentage = (from p1 in context.LookupTable
                 from p2 in context.lookupTablePerUnit
                 where p2.LookupValue <= value1 and p1.ID=p2.LookupID
                 orderby p2.range descending
                 select p1.Percentage).First();
```

Where `context` is your `ObjectContext` instance. Note that Entity Framework may erroneously pluralized your entity names, so `LookupTable` and `LookupTablePerUnit` may actually be something like `LookupTables` and `lookupTablePerUnits` in your `ObjectContext` (and `lookupTablePerUnit` may be capitalized).