# I have a problem while migrating SQL query to Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have this SQL query but I can not transfer it to linq query Entity Framework.

```
SELECT 
    RB.CustomerId AS ID, C.FullName AS 'FULL NAME', 
    C.PhoneNumber AS 'PHONE NUMBER', 
    COUNT(RB.CustomerId) AS BOOKS 
FROM  
    RentedBooks RB
JOIN 
    Customers C ON RB.CustomerId = C.Id
GROUP BY  
    C.FullName, C.PhoneNumber, RB.CustomerId;
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339732/convert-sql-to-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is equivalent of your query in linq:

```
var query = db.RentedBooks.GroupBy(x => new { x.Customer.FullName, x.CustomerId ,x.Customer.PhoneNumber })
.Select(x => new { ID = x.Key.CustomerId,
        x.Key.FullName,
        ,x.Key.PhoneNumber,Books = x.Count() });
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @RobThis is so obvious! The equivalent query in EF.

Comment: I would just expand `Books = x.Count()` for the book count. Prettifying the field names (i.e. "Full Name") can be done when displaying the data.

Comment: @StevePy Yes you are right, I've edited the answer.