# SQL to LINQ generator

Tags: sql, linq, generator

I am new to LINQ and just wanna know; is there any application in which I type standard SQL and it gives me its representing statement in linq?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL to LINQ Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous SO on similar topic:
[SQL to LINQ Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)