# SQL query LINQ To SQL equivalent

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Please, tell me how to convert this SQL query in LINQ To SQL? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT [Movies].[Name]
FROM
(
    SELECT [Value]
    FROM [Index]
    WHERE ('WORD1' = [Word] and [MatchCount] = 1) 
    OR    ([Word] = 'WORD2' AND [MatchCount] = 1)
    GROUP BY [Value]
    HAVING COUNT([Value]) = 2
) AS [Guids]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Movies] ON [Movies].[Guid] = [Guids].[Value]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? **(Warning, following code is untested!)**

```
var q = from i in Index
  where i.MatchCount == 1 &&
  (i.Word == "WORD1" || i.Word == "WORD2")
  group i by i.Value into g
  where g.Count() == 2
  from m in Movies.Where(x => x.Guid == g.Key).DefaultIfEmpty()
  select m.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool), someone suggested [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/).

I've never used it myself, honestly, but I have used [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) extensively. It does the opposite (as well as converting LINQ to lambda expressions), and is one of my favorite tools.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the Linqer, but for a given query, it generated a very difficult solution, which executes much longer than SQL query.

Comment: I'd verify the Linqer query in LinqPad to see if the SQL generated from that LINQ statement actually matched the SQL query you provided above.