# Convert to LINQ using inner join on group

Tags: linq

Does anyone know if there is a tool to convert T-SQL code to LINQ?
I'm struggling to find a way of converting the following SQL code to LINQ:

```
select * from actions as a
inner join 
(
    select max(actionid) as maxactionid, threaduid from actions as a
    where a.actiontypeid not in (3,4)
    group by threaduid
) as a2 on a2.maxactionid = a.actionid
where a.userid <> 2
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: Great tool, although I think I could have worked it out myself if I'd had the patience;) I had to split the query into 2 and translate each query independently then join them up as the tool complained of an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is linqer from http://www.sqltolinq.com/.

Linqer is a SQL to LINQ converter tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and convert your existing SQL statements.