# Convert SQL to equivalent LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

is there any way i can convert below syntax to LINQ equivalent.

```
select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(cour_date) , 0 ) - 1 ),count(*)
from course
where cour_date>CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(GETDATE())) + '-01' + '-01'
and cour_deleted is null and cour_type='Group'
group by month(cour_date)
order by month(cour_date)
```

Comment: You might have some luck with this tool http://www.sqltolinq.com/ There are several others mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Comment: How about having a go then showing us what you tried, Stack Overflow is not a code factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var query = from c in course 
            where c.cour_date > DateTime.Parse("2011-01-01") 
                 && c.cour_deleted == null && c.cour_type.Equals("Group") 
            orderby c.cour_date 
            group c by c.cour_date.Month
```

For each `IGrouping<DateTime, course>` in the query you have the Count value, and you can also format the DateTime value of cour_date to convert mount in a string.