# Convert SQL query in LINQ query and move results into new datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable, and need to extract the data by using this SQL query:

```
SELECT code_direction, count(TP) AS CN FROM table1 WHERE 
                  cod_time = 'A011' GROUP BY TP,code_direction;
```

Which is the C# LINQ equivalent query?
After it I want to move the results into a new DataTable.

I tried many examples founded around in web but no this specific logic.

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1):

Linqer is your friend!

This tool can translate SQL to LINQ. You can download it at http://www.sqltolinq.com.

Note that it's not always possible to convert a SQL query straight into a 100% equivalent LINQ query, but it should be close enough.

If you need translation in the other direction -- from LINQ to SQL -- you can use LINQPad. Download it at http://www.linqpad.net/.

Comment: Has Linqer resolved their virus warnings? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool

Comment: It appears they have.  Just downloaded it and ran it and NAV Corporate installed on my machine didn't complain.  He's apparently been fighting this for a while.  Seems that it was due to a compression tool he was using?  http://sqltolinq.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=general&action=display&thread=58