# T-SQL to LINQ conversion

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    c.CorpSystemID, c.SystemName  , 
    case when a.TaskItemID is NULL then 'false' else 'true' end as Assigned
FROM CorpSystems c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT CorpSystemID, TASKItemID 
      FROM AffectedSystems 
      where TASKItemID = 1) a ON c.CorpSystemID = a.CorpSystemID
```

Can anyone please help me to convert this statement to LINQ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself? (https://www.google.ca/search?ix=hca&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linq+to+sql+examples)

Comment: Showing you the LINQ query is only somewhat useful.  You need to gather the context either in Memory or via a remote LINQ provider like LINQ to SQL or entity framework to make the LINQ function in place of the T-SQL.  This is why its useful to give it a shot yourself first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so assume you've got a list of your `CorpSystem` objects in a variable called `Corpsystems` and a list of your `AffectedSystem` objects in a variable called `AffectedSystems`. Try the following:

**Edit: For a join on all Affected Systems, try this:**

```
var matches = from c in CorpSystems
              join a in AffectedSystems on c.CorpSystemId equals a.CorpSystemId into ac
              from subSystem in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
                     {
                         c.CorpSystemId,
                         c.SystemName,
                         Assigned = subSystem != null && subSystem.TaskItemId != null
                     };
```

**Or for just AffectedSystems that have a TaskItemId of 1:**

```
var matches = from c in CorpSystems
              join a in AffectedSystems.Where(as => as.TaskItemId == 1)
                  on c.CorpSystemId equals a.CorpSystemId into ac
              from subSystem in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
                     {
                         c.CorpSystemId,
                         c.SystemName,
                         Assigned = subSystem != null && subSystem.TaskItemId != null
                     };
```

Comment: he has a left outer join not an inner join

Comment: this creates inner join not outer

Comment: @user1313789 Nah it's a left outer join. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx although I did edit unless you are using the code before I edited?

Comment: on the line where a.TaskItemID == 1  it creates error 'a does not exists'

Comment: this is not valid 'ac.TaskItemID == 1'

Comment: @user1313789 DOH, check my new edit, sorry I should have used the `subSystem` variable instead of ac, as I've projected into it.

Comment: CorpSystems has 7 records and I'm expecting all 7 back, instead I got 4 records? But thank you for trying:-)

Comment: That's probably because of the where clause, if you take that out you should get them all. Do you need only AffectedSystems with a TaskItemId of 1?

Comment: Check my edit, I've done both with a check where the AffectedSystem TaskItemId is 1 and one without the check on the TaskItemId.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped, we got there in the end :) hehe

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to the following SO question [SQL to LINQ Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool), assuming that you do not want to go through the process by hand.