# convert sql to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to implement a Filter by Date on my hotel reservation project.

Could somebody help me please to **convert this sql  code to linq** .

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Room r LEFT JOIN Reservation v ON r.RoomID = v.RoomID
AND NOT (@StartDate >= Date_Check_Out OR @EndDate <= Date_Check_In)
AND v.cancel = 0
WHERE v.ReservationID IS NULL
```

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of good tool to convert SQL to Linq : [**Linqer**](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)

Try out this query

```
var q = (from r in Room 
            join v in Reservation on r.RoomID equals v.RoomID  into outer
            from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where !(o.Date_Check_Out<= startdate || o.Date_Check_In>=endDate)
                  && v.cancel == 0 && v.ReservationID == null 
            select r);
```

Also check this :

See [SQL to LINQ Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)
 existing thread.

If you decide to do it by hand, [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) should be useful.

You also like to see : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html) some good exaple by graphical representation...

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
DateTime startDate, EndDate;

var bookings = from r in Rooms
               join v in Reservation
                   on r.RoomID equals v.RoomID into RoomReservation 
                  from v in RoomReservation.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where
               (Date_Check_Out < startDate || Date_Check_In > endDate)
               select r;
```

Comment: vhat is RoomReservation a table?

Comment: It's an intermediary data structure that was created by the "into" statement used to create the left join in conjunction with DefaultIfEmpty

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
DateTime StartDate=DateTime.Now;
DateTime EndDate=DateTime.Now; 

var result= (
    from r in Room
    from v in Reservation
        .Where(a=>
            a.RoomID == r.RoomID
            && 
            !(
                StartDate>=a.Date_Check_Out ||
                EndDate <=a.Date_Check_In
            )
            && a.cancel==false
        ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where v.ReservationID == null
    select r
    );
```