# LinqPad - Convert SQL to Linq command

Tags: linqpad

I recently purchased LINQPad in hopes that it would allow me to convert SQL statements into LINQ statements.

Using LINQPad, I am able to attach a DB and run the SQL statement which returns the results I need.

But I can not find a 'command' to convert that SQL statement into LINQ.

Can you please let me know how to convert SQL to LINQ by using LINQPad OR another tool?

Comment: There is a tool: see my answer below

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general there are no tools to covert SQL to Linq as @andres-abel mention before, but sometimes you have to write Linq that will execute exactly as specified SQL (for example because of performance issues, backward compatability or some other reasons).

In this case *I'll advice you to do reverse engineering by yourself*:

1. configure logging of dump SQL statements generated by Linq to `stdout` using

   - [`ObjectQuery.ToTraceString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx),
   - [`DbCommand.CommandText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx),
   - [logger availabe to your data source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26066/Redirect-LINQ-to-SQL-DataContext-Log-Messages-To-L)
2. manually rewrite Linq statement until you'll get what you need

Comment: Linqpad does have a really nice translation of the Linq query to SQL (although it does so using the .Net Linq-to-SQL library, so your mileage may vary). I've found it does a great job of educating those just starting on Linq but familiar with SQL as well as verifying that what I wrote in Linq is producing results analogous to a SQL query.

Answer (score 51):

There is a tool called [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/), but be careful: transliterating from SQL to LINQ can give you the [worst of both worlds](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302/suggestions/194040).

For instance, suppose you want all purchases of $1000 or greater paid for in cash or by customers who live in Washington. Here's the query in SQL:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Purchase p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Customer c INNER JOIN Address a ON c.AddressID = a.ID
    ON p.CustomerID = c.ID  
WHERE
   (a.State = 'WA' || p.CustomerID IS NULL)
    AND p.ID in
    (
        SELECT PurchaseID FROM PurchaseItem
        GROUP BY PurchaseID HAVING SUM (SaleAmount) > 1000
    )
```

How would translate this to LINQ? The wrong way is to *transliterate* the query into LINQ, trying to reproduce the outer and inner joins, subquery and group clause. The right way is to map your original query (in English) directly into LINQ, leveraging LINQ's linear flow of data and association properties:

**I want all purchases...**

```
from p in db.Purchases
```

**...of $1000 or greater...**

```
where p.PurchaseItems.Sum (pi => pi.SaleAmount) > 1000
```

**...paid for in cash...**

```
where p.Customer == null
```

**...or by customers who live in Washington**

```
|| p.Customer.Address.State == "WA"
```

Here's the final query:

```
from p in db.Purchases
where p.PurchaseItems.Sum (pi => pi.SaleAmount) > 1000
where p.Customer == null || p.Customer.Address.State == "WA"
select p
```

More info [here](https://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, well, it's easy for you, Joe! :)

Comment: [how to convert MySQL to LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057323/unable-to-convert-mysql-query-to-linq)?

Comment: dead link @Moeez

Answer (score 8):

LinqPad contains no SQL->LINQ translator. LinqPad does actually not contain any LINQ->SQL translator either. It relies on the .Net Linq-to-Sql library or Entity framework for the translation.

I don't know of any other tool with that capability either. In simple cases it would be possible to make one, but for more complex scenarios it would be impossible as there is no LINQ expression that matches some SQL constructs.

Comment: You might mean vice versa. It contains `LINQ -> SQL` instead.