# LinqPad - write SQL and it converts to Linq Lambda

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, linqpad

Does LinqPad have a way such that you write the query in SQL and it converts to Lambda Expressions in Linq?

Comment: Probably not. It works the other way around.

Comment: I also would like to have some *Pad, that you write your task to and it converts it to code.

Comment: I'd imagine you could write something in VS that could do this, but it would be very complex and difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12240849/46223

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinqPad - Convert SQL to Linq command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238423/linqpad-convert-sql-to-linq-command)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQPad doesn't do this.

But [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) does!

Comment: @MayankPathak, Yes but it doesn't do what the OP asked for

Comment: How can we force Linqer to use method syntax instead of query syntax?