# SQL Server Group by using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using Entity Framework in my sample application. It has two DbSets `TICKETS`  and `DEPARTMENT` which correspond to `TICKETS` and `DEPARTMENT` sql server tables.

I would like to write LINQ query which would result in below sql query or produce output similar to it.

```
SELECT   D.NAME as DeptName, T.STATUS as Status, COUNT(1) as Count
FROM     TICKETS T
      , DEPARTMENT D 
WHERE    T.FK_DEPT_ID = D.PK_DEPT_ID
GROUP BY D.NAME , T.STATUS;
```

Comment: you could use something like [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to test/generate your linq query. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238423/linqpad-convert-sql-to-linq-command) for more help

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Besides: Is there any reason why you don't use a join?

Comment: @serv , I  have used LINQ joins , but was not able to get the desired output.

Comment: I primarily meant in your SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use following LINQ-Query to achieve your result:

```
var result = from t in conn.TICKETS
             join dept in conn.DEPARTMENT on t.FK_DEPT_ID equals dept.PK_DEPT_ID
             select new { DeptName = dept.NAME, Status = t.STATUS }
             into temp
             group temp by new { temp.DeptName, temp.Status }
             into g
             select new { g.Key.DeptName, g.Key.Status, Count = g.Count()};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method syntax too.

```
db.Tickets.Join(db.Department,t=>t.FK_DEPT_ID,d=>d.PK_DEPT_ID,(x,y)=>new{x.STATUS,y.NAME})
          .GroupBy(g=>new {g.STATUS,g.NAME})
          .Select(z=>new {z.Key.Name,z.key.STATUS,z.Count()})
```

Comment: Yes this too works, but I guess this is similar to @xxMUROxx answer, but written in method syntax. Thanks

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned in the answer. This is method syntax.

Comment: I did not see that , sorry