# LINQPad 6 how convert sql to linq

Tags: linqpad, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the premium version of LINQPad 6
do you know the steps to convert sql code to linq ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinqPad - Convert SQL to Linq command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238423/linqpad-convert-sql-to-linq-command)

Comment: that was 7 years ago, i suppose in the current version should be some steps for doing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. LINQPad doesn't support it
2. Linqer support it,but if it's complex sql then converter sometime will convert slowquery LINQ-SQL.the logic is like you can convert C# data to json,but when you try to convert json to C# class it will not convert 100% perfect .

PS:
Linqer's link : [Linqer | SQL to LINQ converter](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)