# Convert sql to LINQ TOP 1 NOT in

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do I convert this SQL to LINQ?

```
Select Top 1 iD, Grad from tbl1 
WHERE tbl1.ID not in 
(Select GradId from tbl2 WHERE ID = 99469)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the easiest way would be this:

```
var grads = 
    (from r in tbl2 
     where r.ID == 99469 
     select r.GradID);
var results = 
    (from r in tbl1
     where !grads.Contains(r.ID)
     select new { r.ID, r.Grad })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or for a little more brevity:

```
var grads = ...
var results = tbl1
    .Select(r => new { r.ID, r.Grad })
    .FirstOrDefault(r => !grads.Contains(r.ID));
```

Comment: This one fits my needs:

    var sidstegrad = (from d in db.GetTable<tbl2>()
                      where d.Skif == SKIF
                      orderby d.GradID descending
                      select d.GradID).First();

    var nextGrad = from d in db.GetTable<tbl1>()
                       where Convert.ToInt32(d.iD) > sidstegrad
                       select new { d.Grad, d.iD };

Answer (score 1):

Something on the lines of:

```
 var query =
         (from c in db.tbl1
          where !(from d in db.tbl2
          select d.id)
               .Contains(c.id)
          select c).Take(1)
```