# C# SQL table select and count distinct values

Tags: c#, asp.net, qsqldatabase

i have ASP website with SQL database table. in this table column mane "type".
i want to get all distinct values from this column with values count in datatable.
for example for database table:

```
id  type
---------
1   type1
2   type2
3   type3
4   type2
5   type2
6   type3
```

i want to get the following datatable:

```
type  count
------------
type1   1
type2   3
type3   2
```

Comment: Select Type,Count(type) from TableName Order by Type GroupBy Type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) as count
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY type
```

Result

```
|  type | count |
|-------|-------|
| type1 |     1 |
| type2 |     3 |
| type3 |     2 |
```

<kbd>[`SqlFiddle DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d020c2/3)</kbd>

Comment: Very helpful answer Thank you. In addition to that could you please show how to write this query in Linq?

Comment: @AbdulhakimZeinu You can check this answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/296972/447156

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do this in sql itself by using following query

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) as count
FROM myTableName 
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: it doesnt count the values.i get all count as '1'

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) as count
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY type
```

Linq

```
from t in <YourEntityObject>.YourTableName 
group t by t.type into myVar 
select new
   {
         k = myVar.Key,
         c = myVar.Count()
   };
```