# Convert union all and Subquery SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Any help to convert my below SQL to linq query?

```
SELECT *
FROM BaseCategory
WHERE
    Id = (SELECT ParentId FROM BaseCategory WHERE Id = 10)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM BaseCategory
WHERE
    ParentId = (SELECT ParentId FROM BaseCategory WHERE Id = 10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to LINQ Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var query = (from c in db.BaseCategory 
            where c.Id = (From c1 in db.BaseCategory 
                          where c1.Id == 10 select c1.ParentId) 
            select c)
            .Concat
            (from c in db.BaseCategory 
            where c.ParentId = (From c1 in db.BaseCategory 
                                where c1.Id == 10 select c1.ParentId) 
            select c)
```

Comment: why Concat, why not Union as expected by the OP

Comment: Because `Concat` is the LINQ equivalent of `UNION ALL` in SQL.