# Converting a SQL join into LINQ with EF with filtering

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm learning Entity Framework and attempting to convert an existing SQL query to a LINQ query, but struggling to convert it.

```
SELECT taskItems.Description,taskItemResponses.IsCompleted,TaskItemResponses.userId,TaskItemResponses.Notes 
FROM TaskLists
LEFT JOIN TaskItems ON TaskLists.TaskListId = TaskItems.TaskListId
LEFT JOIN TaskItemResponses ON TaskItemResponses.TaskItemId = TaskItems.TaskItemId 
AND TaskItemResponses.UserId = '1'
```

This works fine for me, it brings back the following data, always showing the list of Tasks, and if a user has responded to any of them, if they've completed it and what notes they've added.

```
Description  IsCompleted   userId  Notes
Task A       NULL          NULL    NULL
Task B       NULL          NULL    NULL
Task C       NULL          NULL    NULL
Task D       1             1       I've done this now.
Task E       NULL          NULL    NULL
```

But when I'm trying to convert this to a LINQ query within C# I can't figure out the syntax, so far i've got

```
var query = from t in DbContext.TaskList
join ti in DbContext.TaskItem on t.TaskListId equals ti.TaskListId
join tr in DbContext.TaskItemResponse on ti.TaskItemId equals tr.TaskItemId into trj
from x in trj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where x.UserId == userId
select t;
```

But this isn't filtering for a particular UserId, and instead returns

```
Description  IsCompleted   userId  Notes
Task A       0             2       Great
Task B       1             2       Okay
Task C       1             3       Nope
Task D       1             1       I've done this now.
Task E       0             5       Ok.
```

Comment: What is `trj` in your EF code, its not defined anywhere

Comment: Using INTO https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see the `into` in your code. My Bad. Another point, your original sql had 2 left joins, your EF has an inner join and a left join - could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to convert SQL `LEFT JOIN` with right side filter to LINQ is to apply the right side filter **before** the `join` operator.

Here is the LINQ equivalent of your SQL query (of course you can correct the field names/types if needed):

```
var query = 
    from t in DbContext.TaskList
    join ti in DbContext.TaskItem on t.TaskListId equals ti.TaskListId
    into tij from ti in tij.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
    join tr in DbContext.TaskItemResponse.Where(x => x.UserId == userId) // filter
        on ti.TaskItemId equals tr.TaskItemId
    into trj from tr in trj.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
    select new
    {
        ti.Description,
        IsCompleted = (bool?)tr.IsCompleted,
        userId = (int?)tr.userId,
        tr.Notes 
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

> See that. May be you need ome minor changes.

```
var query = from t in DbContext.TaskList
    join ti in DbContext.TaskItem on t.TaskListId equals ti.TaskListId
    join tr in DbContext.TaskItemResponse on ti.TaskItemId equals tr.TaskItemId
    where(tr.UserId == '1')
    select new tempObjList
    {
        Description = taskItems.Description,
        IsCompleted = taskItemResponses.IsCompleted,
        userId = TaskItemResponses.userId,
        Notes = TaskItemResponses.Notes
    };
```

make "tempObjList" model class.

Answer (score 0):

In your EF code, the first join is an INNER join and your second one is a LEFT OUTER join

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these:

- [First Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)
- [Second Option](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Hope these could save you some time.