# Need sql query to get two consucutive slots from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table name Availableslots. it contains 2 columns

```
1.WorkerId (int)
2.StartDate (DateTime)
```

StartDate contains availability of all workers.

Now I need a query that select n number of consucutive slots ... like

```
WorkerId  StartDate
1         31/01/2018 09:00
1         31/01/2018 10:00
2         31/01/2018 09:00
3         31/01/2018 09:00
3         31/01/2018 10:00
4         31/01/2018 09:00
```

As per this data only worker 1 and 3 has 2 continuous slots available.
I am passing these slots as parameter.

I am using MSSQL.

**Note:-**
I am passing time slot as a parameter and that is not fixed. It may vary from 2 to n numbers...

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes do data/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Column StartDate data type?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT WorkerID, count(StartDate)
from Availableslots
where
StartDate in (date, date)
group by WorkerID
having count(StartDate) = 2 (or > 2, how you need)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Not exactly. I am passing time slots as a parameter like in this case I am passing 09:00 and 10:00. This slots not fixed sometimes 2 sometimes 5. I need to check on specific date all times available. Am I clear?

Comment: This is for MSSQL @Jarlh

Comment: @vikas as you maybe know, you can use this statement in oracle, mysql, mssql .. and maybe more dbms because I'm not using specific functions or others ..

Comment: Thanks @F.Lazarescu. It is quite close and after few changes working fine. Now I am converting this to linq query

Comment: @F.Lazarescu any help to convert this to linq ?

Comment: @vikas, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool) helping you?

Comment: Yes @F.Lazarescu

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should define what is continuous slots and what is not continuous slots with suitable example.

```
 declare @t table(WorkerId int,StartDate datetime)
insert into @t VALUES
(1, '2018/01/31 09:00')
,(1,'2018/01/31 10:00')
,(2,'2018/01/31 09:00')
,(3,'2018/01/31 09:00')
,(3,'2018/01/31 10:00')
,(4,'2018/01/31 09:00')

declare @timeSlot int=2
;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY workerid ORDER BY StartDate
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT *
FROM @t t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte c
        WHERE c.workerid = t.workerid
            AND c.rn >=@timeSlot --( how you need)
        )
```