# SQL IN Operator to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need this query to be translated to Linq query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (pf.Id)
FROM
    PF pf
    LEFT JOIN FA fa on pf.id = fa.PFId
    LEFT JOIN Fan f ON pf.FId = f.Id
WHERE
  pf.PId=2 AND fa.AId IN (1,26) AND fa.AId NOT IN(27)
```

This is the LINQ query I have so far as requested

```cs
var allFansSavedAsLeads =  _dbContext.PF
                           .Where(e => e.F.S != null &&
                           e.A.Any(x => x.AId==27 && 
                           x.AId.Equals(1) /*&& 
                           x.AId != 27*/) && 
                           e.PId == pId);
```

I get zero results with this.

Comment: Can you please update the post with your LINQ query that you are having

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to LINQ Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Comment: x.ActivityId cannot both equal 27 and 1. You need an OR (||) not an AND (&&) there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you Create two lists of Ids representing the Activities that can be included and activities which needs to be excluded. use them like the following:

```
List<int> IncludedIds = new List<int>(){1,26};
List<int> ExcludedIds = new List<int>(){27};
_dbContext.ProfileFans.Where(e => e.Fan.SNUrl != null && 
                             e.Activities.Any(x => IncludedIds.Any(x.ActivityId) && 
                                                   !ExcludedIds.Any(x.ActivityId) && 
                                                   e.ProfileId == profileId);
```

**Please note**: I used `List<int>` because of the example that you are given, you have to create the lists based on the data type of `ActivityId`

Comment: The exclude/black list is completely useless.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti: yes until and unless there is only one item in that list.

Comment: Even if there are more items in that list. If you're taking only IDs 1 and 26, then by definition the ID can't be 27, and it can't be 28, and it can't be 29... Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57270025/9945524 to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary `ActivityList` AS

```
var List<int> ActivityList = new List<int>() {1, 26}
```

and use something like

```
ActivityList.Contains(x => x.ActivityId)
```

But see sujith's answer for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a whitelist and a blacklist. It's either one or the other. So I'm making a whitelist. If the allowed ActivityId is 1 or 26, then by definition it is definitely not 27, so there is no need to try and exclude it. I'm using `int[]` instead of `List<int>` given that the whitelist is likely to be static, but feel free to change this to a `List<int>` if you want to dynamically modify it.

```
int[] whiteList = { 1, 26 };
var allFansSavedAsLeads = _dbContext.ProfileFans.Where(pf =>
    pf.Fan.SNUrl.HasValue &&
    pf.Activities.Any(fa => whiteList.Contains(fa.ActivityId)));
```

If you want the JOINs as well, you may want to look into `.Include()`, but from your original SQL query you seem like you're not going to actually need the contents of the joined tables.