# Wants this Sql Query in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

How to write below given Sql Query in Linq?

```
SELECT  
    Invoice.ExtInvoiceId AS Id, 
    Invoice.ExtClientBranchId, 
    Invoice.CustomerReference,
    Invoice.CountryDataSetId,
    Invoice.JmsJobNumber,
    Invoice.InvoiceDate,
    Invoice.TotalAmount,
    Invoice.RequestedBy,
    Invoice.DateCreated,
    PaidTable.Paid,
    Invoice.So_Terms_Disc,
    '' AS RequestedByValue,
    Client.ParentId,
    Invoice.CurrencyCode 

FROM Invoice 

INNER JOIN Client 
    ON Invoice.ExtClientBranchId = Client.ExtClientBranchId 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ExtInvoiceId,
        (CASE WHEN SUM(TotalAmount) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Paid 

    FROM [Transaction] GROUP BY ExtInvoiceId
) AS PaidTable 
    ON Invoice.ExtInvoiceId = PaidTable.ExtInvoiceId
```

Comment: you could show us what you have tried

Comment: You have to translate it step by step. At the start don't focus to mutch on the long list of column you need to select.  Get a brunch of ID to validate your result and start joining table one by one. If you fail to translate some SQL key word hit a search engine with "[insert SQL keywords] LinQ". And remember LinQ is lazy, you can cut your query in smaller part for readability.

Comment: In a world with an [mcve], and definition of those table, perhaps some of the join and clause won't be usefull as the relation will be well define. But who knows.

Comment: @Gabriel LloricoI am trying this                                                                                               var invoiceModels = (
                                             from d in db.Invoices
                                             join j in db.Clients on d.ExtClientBranchId equals j.ExtClientBranchId into yGroup
                                             from y1 in yGroup.DefaultIfEmpty())                            but query under Left Outer Join I am unable to understand how to write it.

Comment: @Diya what i mean is the `linq` code you have tried :)

Comment: I believe that there are sites online where you can do this see [here](https://www.sqltolinq.com/), also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool)

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey yes the query looks it has few operations/join to be dealt with , so approach it step by step :

- Fetch all the records , using inner join
- Try using left outer join
- Further simplify the query to the best of what you need.

Also note if you are visual-studio , it gives you this best interface wherein you can get to know at which point your linq is correct and what all options you can use with it.