# Sql to Linq. how can i translate? Is there a translation program?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Musteriler.MusteriAdiSoyadi,Sum(Odemeler.OdemeTutari) AS ToplamOdeme FROM Odemeler
Right JOIN Musteriler ON Odemeler.OdeyenId = Musteriler.Id
GROUP BY Musteriler.MusteriAdiSoyadi,Musteriler.KayitTarihi ORDER BY Musteriler.MusteriAdiSoyadi;
```

How do I convert the running sql query to linq

Comment: Do you already have a database context? Did you try anything, even if it didn't give correct results yet?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296972/sql-to-linq-tool